# How to convert from String to specific types using PropertyEditor

Tags: java, java-8, propertyeditor

I am trying to pass any class type besides a java.lang primitive types such as java.math (e.g., java.math.BigInteger) types and customized build in types (e.g., com.parse.MyOwnType).  The method below only does for primitive types.  Anyone has a suggestion on how to use PropertyEditor besides primitive types? Are there other editor libraries that can be used for conversion?

```
import java.beans.PropertyEditor;
import java.beans.PropertyEditorManager;

private Object convert(Class<?> targetType, String text) {
    PropertyEditor editor = PropertyEditorManager.findEditor(targetType);
    editor.setAsText(text);
    return editor.getValue();
}
```

Comment: Can you add a sample use case that you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I don't think the below will answer your question directly it may give you some guidance or help in regards to how you may achieve your specific use case.

Java docs on [Upper Bounds](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/upperBounded.html)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    convert(MyOwnType.class, "Works!");
    convert(String.class, "Compilation Issue!");
}

static Object convert(Class<? extends MyType> targetType, String text) {
    PropertyEditor editor = PropertyEditorManager.findEditor(targetType);
    editor.setAsText(text);
    return editor.getValue();
}

static class MyOwnType extends MyType {

}

static abstract class MyType {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Garreth Golding, I will give it a try! Thanks for the guidance!